# Libgdx sensor listener

Tags: java, android, libgdx, touch

I'm making a game for Android using LibGDX in Java. Sometimes (more often) few seconds after the game began, it freezes for few moments (FPS drops to 40-30 from 60) and continues alright.
The log says this:

> 10-01 23:43:24.334    2374-2395/com.gadarts.parashoot.android
>   I/AndroidGraphics﹕ paused
>
> 10-01 23:43:24.334    2374-2374/com.gadarts.parashoot.android
>   I/AndroidInput﹕ sensor listener tear down
>
> 10-01 23:43:24.693    2374-2374/com.gadarts.parashoot.android
>   I/AndroidInput﹕ sensor listener setup
>
> 10-01 23:43:24.713    2374-2395/com.gadarts.parashoot.android
>   I/AndroidGraphics﹕ resumed

I looked around the web about that and couldn't find anything relevant.

In my main class I put this line, in the create():

```
TouchHandler touchHandler = new TouchHandler(this);
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(touchHandler);
```

TouchHandler is a class I wrote which implements InputProcessor.

Anybody have any idea?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Those log messages are normal. My best guess is that you are instantiating and throwing away a lot of objects in your render loop. Look for places where you use the `new` keyword anywhere in your render loop, especially within a `for` loop.

Comment: Actually I don't have places in the render loop where I instantiate and throwing away a lot of objects. I'm really careful with these stuff (I also use lots of object pools).
The log I posted above happens in the same moment the game pauses for few moments.

Comment: That sounds like Android is pausing your Application momentarily. Libgdx's response (unregistering sensor listeners) is expected in this case. But as far as I know, that should only happen if it's putting another Application or Dialog on screen in front of your app. Not sure what could be causing this.

Comment: Check whether you are not calling render method recursively. For example by calling  Gdx.graphics.requestRendering().

Comment: Nope, I checked my code and couldn't find anything recursive.

Comment: I am also facing same issue in my game, ill post if  I found anything prolific from my tests.

Comment: @kingAm did you find anything? Is it part of garbage collection?

Comment: I did found out but forgot to update here, the problem was i was calling sensor listener in render method too many times. In order to resolve it, I put a flag for listener based on some time gap like half or 1 seconds.